# MSAccess error with a version of file on pc - OCX

Tags: ms-access, ocx

I have an Access 2003 application that users recently started having issues with the day I put out a new version, one of the screens has a field that has a default value of 'date()', instead of showing the date it shows '#name?'.  I'm sure this if some out of synch dll or ocx but not sure which one.  Anybody know?  I rolled back to a previous version of the application on the users machine and they are fine now (but I'll need to keep pushing out new versions with new functionality soon).  So I think some file on my development box got updated just not sure which one.

Thanks

Don

Answer (score 0):

This is typical of a missing reference. If your are using ActiveX controls, you could easily be missing something on the other PCs. Another common cause is using early binding and library references.

Missing references often affect the VBA core functions such as Date.

Comment: None of the references show as missing, couldn't be that easy, I'm thinking it the dao file so I'll try to replace that first, just hoping someone would now that actual file that provides the Date function.

Comment: `Property Date As Variant Member of VBA.DateTime`, hence my comment about VBA core functions. Have you a variable called date that redefines date?